# Change ImageView size in a recyclerview after Picasso.load()?

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso, gridlayoutmanager

I have:

- a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager
- grid item layout with an ImageView in it (with height wrap_content and width match_parent) wrapped in a Framelayout, so the image is bottom|center_horizontal aligned
- Picasso loading an image into ImageView asynchronously from the web

Current situation:
The image is loaded into the imageView, but the imageview's size is the recycled grid item's imageview's size.

What I would like to achieve:
After loading the image into the imageview, resize the imageview on runtime (redraw).

What I have tried:

1. notifyItemChanged() - could do the trick (in theory at least), but I
   am not able to check if the current grid item's view is in layout
   state, so my app crashed with IllegalStateException
2. listening to Picasso's load with a Callback, and onSuccess() check the imageview drawable aspectratio and try to resize the imageview itself with
   requestLayout(). Did not work. (Well it worked, but only when there
   is an animation or something triggering the redraw of the layout. If
   there is nothing, then the imageview is not redrawn.)
3. listening to Picasso's load with a Callback, and onSuccess() start an animation animating the alpha of the imageview. This would trigger the redraw. But this sometimes worked sometimes not(and I don't know why).

Answer (score 4):

What I did was putting an ImageView into FrameLayout and then changing this FrameLayout's size to needed. Hope it would help you.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

P.S. changing FrameLayout's size:

viewHolder.frame.setMinimumWidth(neededWidth);

Comment: And all this in the adapters onBindView() after receiving the image by downloading it with Picasso?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you know the needed width. If you know it, you can set it to frame before loading the image.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso has a function to resize your image. Something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

You can change centerCrop, to play with aspect ratio

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to resize the image to fit the imageview. I want to resize the imageview so the whole image can fit in it.

Comment: I think this is not good solution,if you resize the imageview the UI is inconsistent, for this purpose exist scaleType, if you dont want lost image information use scaletype centerInside, this show all image inside ImageView limits. This is my opinion, in other case i dont know how to help you

Comment: I have to resize the imageview, because I have it in a FrameLayout bottom|center_horizontal aligned (I edited my question also). So since I can use "fitCenter" on the imageview, because I need it centered (fitStart and fitEnd are not ok for me).

Answer (score 0):

I wanna show this using a

**Campaign Banner List Using Dynamic Width - Height Example**

that:

> - Create an **item_campaign_banner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/campaignImageSuperView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/campaignImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/campaign_image_error_icon"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <View
                android:id="@+id/campaignSectionLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/campaignImage"
                android:background="#F2F2F2" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> - Than create a **BannerHolder.java**

```
public class BannerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView campaignImage;
    private View campaignSectionLine;
    private ViewGroup campaignImageSuperView;

    public BannerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        campaignImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.campaignImage);
        campaignSectionLine =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.campaignSectionLine);
        campaignImageSuperView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.campaignImageSuperView);
    }

    public ImageView getCampaignImage() {
        return campaignImage;
    }

    public ViewGroup getCampaignImageSuperView() {
        return campaignImageSuperView;
    }
}
```

> - Than apply this in `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder incomingHolder, int position)` method that
>     your created **YourAdapter.java**

```
if (incomingHolder instanceof BannerHolder) {

    BannerHolder bannerHolder = (BannerHolder) incomingHolder;
            Banner banner = (Banner) campaigns.get(position);

            if(banner != null && banner.getImage() != null && banner.getImage().getWidth() != null && banner.getImage().getHeight() != null) {
                Picasso.with(activity)
                        .load(banner.getImage().getUrl())
                        .error(R.drawable.campaign_image_error_icon)
                        .into(bannerHolder.getCampaignImage());

                bannerHolder.getCampaignImageSuperView().setMinimumWidth(banner.getImage().getWidth());
                bannerHolder.getCampaignImageSuperView().setMinimumHeight(banner.getImage().getHeight());
            }
        }
```

That's all!

[image]